# Issue on Creating a Promise in Javascript

Tags: javascript, promise

Can you please take a look at [this Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/vLknk2nw/) and let me know Why I am not able to correctly create and use the Promise?

```js
var projectInfo = [];
var projectPromise;
var thePromissedProjects;
var projects = [{
    "ProjectID": "15260",
    "Longitude": "-118.641508",
    "Latitude": "51.949915",
}, {
    "ProjectID": "17043",
    "Longitude": "-125.444557",
    "Latitude": "51.097552",
}, {
    "ProjectID": "12910",
    "Longitude": "-130.759074",
    "Latitude": "57.128581",
}, {
    "ProjectID": "15204",
    "Longitude": "-117.947302",
    "Latitude": "52.363281",
}, {
    "ProjectID": "15237",
    "Longitude": "-118.338717",
    "Latitude": "52.013140",
}, {
    "ProjectID": "17040",
    "Longitude": "-125.142283",
    "Latitude": "51.125719",
}, {
    "ProjectID": "12961",
    "Longitude": "-130.430823",
    "Latitude": "57.022356",
}, {
    "ProjectID": "14677",
    "Longitude": "-119.387702",
    "Latitude": "51.896785",
}, {
    "ProjectID": "15212",
    "Longitude": "-118.104450",
    "Latitude": "52.242352",
}];
projectPromise = new Promise(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < projects.length; i++) {
        thePromissedProjects = projects[i];
         }
    return thePromissedProjects;

});
projectPromise.then(printPromisses);

function printPromisses(p){
    console.log(p.ProjectID);
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hmmm, your code does create a promise, but it's not used anywhere, so, how do you know it does not work?

Comment: This code makes no sense. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Gusman, thanks for comment but how can I test it? I already tried `projectPromise();` at the end of snippet but I got error `Uncaught TypeError: projectPromise is not a function`

Comment: projectPromise.Success() or projectPromise.Error()

Comment: wait, no!! XD that's for AngularJS, not JQuery, for JQuery is .done()

Comment: Still getting `Uncaught TypeError: projectPromise.done is not a function` error

Comment: There is no need to use promise in this example..

Comment: wait.. im a bit tired and starting to have crossed cables, a promise is returned by a deferred, so you must create a deferred and use it's promise... let me seek an example for you

Comment: @Gusman You don't even know what the OP is trying to do, stop making wild guesses.

Comment: he asks for creating and using a promise, just that, I don't care if it's example doesn't needs it...

Comment: Take a look at this: http://joseoncode.com/2011/09/26/a-walkthrough-jquery-deferred-and-promise/

Comment: @Gusman, he is looking for promise to use it in example provided. If example does not need promise then there is no point in explaining..

Comment: maybe he created an example which doesn't needs the promise but he is trying to use it in a place where it really is needed, so understanding what is a promise/deferred is necessary, if you don't understand a deferred/promise is really easy to create an example code which does not need it

Comment: @Gusman Way to go, solve a problem you know nothing about using techniques you don't know if they are even necessary with libraries that where not even mentioned (jQuery? Angular?!) for an OP who is unable to explain what they need. Talk about the blind leading the blind.

Comment: Your Promise *semantics* are fine. You just need to inject the `resolve` and `reject` parameters and call them somewhere. But a promise can only be resolved *once*. You either need to create one promise per project, or chain them. And obviously, as others have said, there is no async code here so a promise is not really needed

Comment: Ok seems you guys are angury!

Comment: @Tomalak I wish I could show you the whole code and reason why I ned to use the promise

Comment: @Tomalak Who are you *really* angry at? :) You're right, syntax isn't the correct word. And I agree, I voted to close, but there is nothing wrong with my comment

Comment: I'm not angry, I only find Gusmans undirected enthusiasm and the pointless "I'll pull out some examples, I don't care if I understand the question" attitude rather stunning. -- I was just nitpicking on your comment. The OP's *semantics* are still not fine, though. ;)

Comment: By the way Thanks RGraham for closing this!

Comment: @Suffii Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Make a representative example of your situation. It's never impossible to explain your current programming problem, even without showing your entire code. It just takes a little bit of  effort from your end.

Answer (score 0):

You need to resolve or reject a promise before any callback will be called.

```
projectPromise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  resolve(projects[0]);
});
```

Prints `15260`. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zm64retf/)

You can resolve or reject a promise only once. So if you intended to iterate over the projects and let the callback be executed once per iteration, that won't work.